# Calculate the number of dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, an pennies with random amount of pennies

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a homework in VB.NET where I have to calculate the number of dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, an pennies I will receive when I cash in my pennies at a bank. The number of pennies I have can be random numbers. And so far, my code is here:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict Off
Option Infer Off


Public Class frmMain
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    Dim intDollars As Integer
    Dim intQuarters As Integer
    Dim intDimes As Integer
    Dim intNickels As Integer
    Dim intPennies As Integer

    Integer.TryParse(txtNumPennies.Text, intDollars)
    intDollars = txtNumPennies.Text \ 100
    txtDollars.Text = Convert.ToString(intDollars)

    Integer.TryParse(txtNumPennies.Text, intQuarters)
    intQuarters = (txtNumPennies.Text - txtDollars.Text * 100) \ 25
    txtQuarters.Text = Convert.ToString(intQuarters)

    Integer.TryParse(txtNumPennies.Text, intDimes)
    intDimes = (txtNumPennies.Text Mod 25) \ 10
    txtDimes.Text = Convert.ToString(intDimes)

    Integer.TryParse(txtNumPennies.Text, intNickels)
    intNickels = (txtNumPennies.Text Mod 10) \ 5
    txtNickels.Text = Convert.ToString(intNickels)

    Integer.TryParse(txtNumPennies.Text, intPennies)
    intPennies = (txtNumPennies.Text Mod 5) \ 1
    txtPennies.Text = Convert.ToString(intPennies)

End Sub

Private Sub txtNumPennies_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNumPennies.TextChanged

    txtDollars.Text = String.Empty
    txtQuarters.Text = String.Empty
    txtDimes.Text = String.Empty
    txtNickels.Text = String.Empty
    txtPennies.Text = String.Empty

End Sub
End Class
```

Somehow, it is not calculating right, especially the nickles. I would gladly appreciate any helpful tips! Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Hint, you can't do math operations over text. What does txtDollars.Text * 100 means? Does this even compile? Try working with ints, not strings.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict in Project Properties on the compile tab.

Comment: What is your input? What bad output are you getting?

Comment: @MihailShishkov it does compile. everything seems to be right except the nickels.

Comment: @DStanley my input is random. For example, it can be 13 pennies or 533 pennies. it does not matter what input I put. but it should calculate the number of dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies

Comment: @CyrusRondolos Even if it does compile, **you should NOT do that**. As suggested by Mary, you should turn on `Option Strict` until you get rid of this habit. The compiler will help you do that.

Comment: @CyrusRondolos OK, with what input (specifically) is the output wrong? What is that wrong output? The number of nickels should always be 0 or 1.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed if i turn on the strict option, it gets an error. the thing is, i am new to vb.net so i am not sure with things yet. any suggestions?

Comment: @DStanley for example, if i calculate 26 pennies, then it gives me 1 quarter, 1 nickel and 1 penny. also when i try 533 i get 5 dollars, 1 quarter and 3 pennies.

Comment: Look at what you're doing differently for quarters (which is correct), then apply that to the other coins.

Comment: @DStanley I did apply it to other coins and i tried every possible way and i still get error somehow. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not removing the number of pennies that have already been converted, so you are doubling up on your money (if only real life was that easy!). In addition, you keep trying to convert the text without checking if it is valid - and you are repeating yourself.

```
if Integer.TryParse(txtNumPennies.Text, numPennies) Then
    ' all your conversions go here. I am providing two examples below.
    intDollars = numPennies \ 100
    txtDollars.Text = Convert.ToString(intDollars)
    numPennies = numpennies - (intDollars * 100)

    intQuarters = numpennies \ 25
    txtQuarters.Text = Convert.ToString(intQuarters)
    numPennies = numpennies - (intQuarters * 25)
    ' ... and so on
End If
```

If you follow the logic above, you will see it mirrors what happens in real life - convert pennies to dollars first, the converted pennies no longer exist.

Comment: I am very thankful for your help! I honestly never thought of this. You just helped me solved all the questions i have for myself.  Again, thank you!

Comment: No problems, please remember to mark this answer as the accepted one. Upvotes and accepting answers is the 'currency' within Stack Exchange for showing appreciation.