# Converting cents into amount of change given

Tags: vb.net

So i am having troubles with this code. I get the dollars part to work correctly but the rest is not. Im trying to change 529 cents into 5 dollars 1 quarter 0 dimes 0 nickels 4 pennies, here is my code.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim amount As Integer
    Dim dollars As Integer
    Dim quarters As Integer
    Dim dimes As Integer
    Dim nickels As Integer
    Dim pennies As Integer


    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter A Unit of Cents")
    amount = CInt(Console.ReadLine())


    If (amount >= 100) Then
        dollars = amount \ 100
        amount = amount - (100 * dollars)
    ElseIf (amount >= 25) Then
        quarters = amount \ quarters
        amount = amount - (25 * quarters)
    ElseIf (amount >= 10) Then
        dimes = amount \ dimes
        amount = amount - (10 * dimes)
    ElseIf (amount >= 5) Then
        nickels = amount \ nickels
        amount = amount - (5 * nickels)
    ElseIf (amount >= 1) Then
        pennies = amount
    End If


    Console.WriteLine("" & dollars & " dollars " & quarters & " quarters " & dimes & " dimes " & nickels & " nickels " & pennies & " pennies ")
    Console.ReadLine()


End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any `ElseIf`s.

Comment: Using **[the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** you can find and fix your own bugs rather than waiting for people on the internet to do it for you

Comment: (Else)if only runs once and for one case, you need to check all cases so you will have to do it differently.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first time writing a program from scratched. I will check it when I get off work.

Comment: Seems to be a standard homework question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415682/calculate-the-number-of-dollars-quarters-dimes-nickels-an-pennies-with-rando/50419851#50419851

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to automate the counting of coins. You were almost there. Just use modulo to find the remaining pennies each time a count is done.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim amount As Integer
    Dim dollars As Integer
    Dim quarters As Integer
    Dim dimes As Integer
    Dim nickels As Integer
    Dim pennies As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter A Unit of Cents")
    amount = CInt(Console.ReadLine())

    dollars = parseDenomination(amount, 100)
    quarters = parseDenomination(amount, 25)
    dimes = parseDenomination(amount, 10)
    nickels = parseDenomination(amount, 5)
    pennies = amount

    Console.WriteLine("" & dollars & " dollars " & quarters & " quarters " & dimes & " dimes " & nickels & " nickels " & pennies & " pennies ")
    Console.WriteLine($"{getAmountString(dollars, "Dollar")}, {getAmountString(quarters, "Quarter")}, {getAmountString(dimes, "Dime")}, {getAmountString(nickels, "Nickel")}, {getAmountString(pennies, "Penny")},")
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Private Function parseDenomination(ByRef amount As Integer, count As Integer) As Integer
    Dim result = amount \ count
    amount = amount Mod count
    Return result
End Function

Private Function getAmountString(amount As Integer, name As String) As String
    Return $"{name}{If(amount = 1, "", "s")}: {amount}"
End Function
```

I added an additional method to help get the string output. It kind of breaks down for "pennies / pennys" though - that's English for you.